# How to get camera extrinsincs in Windows Media Foundation?

Tags: c++, uwp

I'm trying to get camera extrinsics from all HoloLens sensors (working in research mode). I've found the CameraExtrinsics structure in Windows Media Foundation ( [here] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfapi/ns-mfapi-mfcameraextrinsics ) but I can't find any example on how to get it. My question is: how can I get to the camera extrinsincs?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution and I'll share it here in case someone else struggles with this as well.

You have to get it from the frame properties ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.frames.mediaframereference.properties?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Media_Capture_Frames_MediaFrameReference_Properties)) via a GUID (in my case the GUID was "6B761658-B7EC-4C3B-8225-8623CABEC31D").